# Transform XML with elements to new elements with attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<message>
  <header>
    <number>abc</number>
    <headerType>
      <code>abc</code>
    </headerType>
  </header>
</message>
```

This structure, I would like to convert to the following structure so that it will be able to be bound to my Telerik RadTreeview control:

```
<Tree>
    <Node Text="message" Value="message">
        <Node Text="header" Value="header">
            <Node Text="number" Value="number">
                <Node Text="abc" Value="abc" />
    </Node>
            <Node Text="headerType" Value="headerType">
                <Node Text="code" Value="code">
                    <Node Text="abc" Value="abc" />
                </Node>
            </Node>
       </Node>
    </Node>
</Tree>
```

Would this transformation be possible with XSLT and if so, what would that XSLT look like?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please show the expected result of the transformation in the given example, and explain the logic behind the transformation (if it's not self-evident - which I suspect it won't be).

Comment: Note also that in XML an element name cannot begin with a digit.

Comment: Sorry, for not being clear! I have simplified the examples and brought them in line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Tree>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </Tree>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <Node Text="{local-name()}" Value="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </Node>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <Node Text="{.}" Value="{.}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that there are no *attributes* in the given XML example and no instructions on how to handle them if they were found.